# why is array_unique not working after array_unshift?

Tags: php

Or maybe I'm doing something else wrong.

```
<?php
$date = "2011-12-31|12-31";

$fileData = file('something.txt'); // Get file contents as array
print_r($fileData);
echo "<br /><br />";

array_unshift($fileData, $date); // Add date to [0]
print_r($fileData);
echo "<br /><br />";

$cleanData = array_unique($fileData); // remove dupes
print_r($cleanData);
echo "<br /><br />";
?>
```

Prints out as:

```
Array ( [0] => 2011-12-31|12-31 [1] => 2011-12-30|12-30 [2] => 2011-12-29|12-29 ) 

Array ( [0] => 2011-12-31|12-31 [1] => 2011-12-31|12-31 [2] => 2011-12-30|12-30 [3] => 2011-12-29|12-29 ) 

Array ( [0] => 2011-12-31|12-31 [1] => 2011-12-31|12-31 [2] => 2011-12-30|12-30 [3] => 2011-12-29|12-29 )
```

Here is something.txt:

```
2011-12-31|12-31
2011-12-30|12-30
2011-12-29|12-29
```

I suspect that there might be eol or lf markers in the `$fileData`. If this is the case, is there an easy way to remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings in the array returned by [`file()`](http://php.net/file) have new line characters at the end, making them not equal to strings which do not. You can tell [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to not include these characters by adding `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as the 2nd parameter:

```
file('something.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: It's easier to spot these kind of issues if you user `var_dump()` and your browser's View Source feature (rather than the `print_r()` rendered as HTML).